# SSRS Reporting - How to disable dataset?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008-r2

My RDL file contain 10 different ds, dataset1... dataset10.
On document I am only using dataset1...dataset5 and rest are obsolete (dataset5 to dataset10)

Report is doing fine but having performance issue as dataset5 to dataset10 are unnecessary loading with the report. I have  client requirement not to delete them ,he wanted keep the old logic.

Is there any way in SSRS where we can disable or deactivate these datasets not to load.

Please help me to this. Thanks .
vd

Comment: u could just release the DS into a folder and delete them in the Report.

Comment: can i rollback then on any point i need then back ? I That will be very tidy to this manual reports having same names e.g. report1datasetname1 report2datasetname1 looking for something some server setting or report setting ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make a copy of the current report, then delete the unneeded datasets in the present version? That way you'll have a retrievable record of the old report and its datasets without having to deploy it to the reporting server. Just click on the report in the solution explorer, then press ctrl+c and ctrl+v.

Comment: I picked this a batter alternate.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, you can use a hidden parameter with a default value (say "1") and use that parameter in the obsolete datasets.

dataset5

```
select
code here
where @parameter <> 1
```

Comment: Thanks  friends, sub way can be many more  but looks there is no True/False option available with the dataset on the RDL file.